# Django Model - ManyToManyField restrict select multiple items from same category

Tags: django

I want to restrict selecting two items from same category and to be able to limit the number of selected items.

exemple models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
 item_categ = models.CharField()


class Product(models.Model):
  item = models.CharField()
  item_categ = models.ForeignKey(Category)


class CombineProducts(models.Model):
  combined = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

I want User to not be able to select two `item`s from with the same `item_categ` and limit to 3 products
How i do that? Thanks

Comment: such a requirement is too complex for database layer constraints, and would be hard to adjust later. so in your view you should enforce these rules with a custom logic.

Comment: The best approach for this is to have that validation within a form or formset rather than your model. You could out it in the model but it would need to be in in the save method before you super it so that you can query the database but it will still not be ideal as you would have committed values to the database and so would then need to handle the rollback.

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript approach

This is DOM related, so you probabily will have to use Javascript instead of Python, unless you want ugly error messages from your backend tell the user that he cant do it.

The logic is simple: you will count the selected itens in total and count by category, if reach any of your rule you can prevent the selection

#### Backend approach

If you want to do it in backend (ugly way), you can just count on your request data amount of selected itens and the selected itens by category and send the user back to the message with some error message telling that he cant do that.

Comment: Hey, i doubt if he can do the same by defining a pre save method where the item category check can be performed.

Comment: i guess is the step before the presave, you can do it as Form Validations, can create one custom validation to setup it, so when run form.is_valid() will fails and return the page... yet backend validations for it is just ugly, be best approach is have both, frontend to be more pretty and in the back to be more safe